# Parametric solution of a system of two nonlinear ODEs with data describing only one the functions

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, parametric-functions

I have the following pair of nonlinear ordinary differential equations

```
m'[t] == gamma*v[t]*m[t] - mu*m[t];
v'[t] ==
  v[t]*(k - epsilon - mu) - v[t]^2*k + m[t]*l - m[t]^2*l - m[t]*v[t]*(k + l + gamma);
```

So there are five parameters gamma, epsilon, mu, k and l. Now I would like to estimate these parameters from data that is only related to the function `m[t]`. I have tried using `ParametricNDSolveValue` together with `FindFit` as usual. The problem what arises is that `ParametricNDSolveValue` gives me a function with two variables `m` and `v` and four parameters. I'm not sure how to write the `FindFit` so it understands that the data is only for `m` and not for `v` at all.

If I only had one differential equation with five parameters, I could easily do the fitting because then it's just a straightforward application of `ParametricNDSolveValue` and `FindFit`. However, as I have two differential equations depending on each other, I cannot do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could specify that only one function should be returned: `ParametricNDSolve[equations, m, {t, tmin, tmax}, {epsilon, mu, k, l}]`

Comment: Initial data and `gamma` are also parameters?

Comment: @AlexTrounev The gamma is. Forgot it. But I think that J.M.s solution might work, but I’m not on my pc to try it yet.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Thank you, that seemed to work. However this whole method seems to be super inefficient, see my new question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182960/estimating-parameters-for-pair-of-differential-equations-efficiently